# Camel Case format conversion using regular expressions in R

Tags: r, regex

I have two related questions regarding regular expressions in R:
[1]
I would like to convert sub-strings, containing punctuation followed by a letter, to an upper case letter.
Example:

```
Dr_dre to: DrDre  
Captain.Spock to: CaptainSpock  
spider-man to: spiderMan
```

[2]
I would like convert camel case strings to lower case strings with underscore delimiter.
Example:

```
EndOfFile to: End_of_file  
CamelCase to: Camel_Case  
ABC to: A_B_C
```

Thanks much,
Kamashay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub`.  We match one or more punctuation characters (`[[:punct:]]+`) followed by a single character which is captured as a group (`(.)`).  In the replacement, the backreference for the capture group (`\\1`) is changed to upper case (`\\U`).

```
sub("[[:punct:]]+(.)", "\\U\\1", str1, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "DrDre"        "CaptainSpock" "spiderMan"
```

For the second case, we use regex lookarounds i.e. match a letter (`(?<=[A-Za-z])`) followed by a capital letter and replace with `_`.

```
gsub("(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[A-Z])", "_", str2, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "End_Of_File" "Camel_Case"  "A_B_C"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("Dr_dre", "Captain.Spock", "spider-man")
str2 <- c("EndOfFile", "CamelCase", "ABC")
```

Comment: wow! thanks for the prompt response - this works. can you briefly explain the regex you are using - specifically - what are '\\U', "?<=...', '?=[..' - thanks again